# How to keep the checkbox status after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, html

I already looked at the other threads but couldn't find anything.
I have one checkbox which hides some table columns by changing it's status but after every refresh it changes to the initial status (checked) and the columns aren't hidden anymore.
Is there any way to keep the status after the refresh? Can I apply local storage in this case and is there a way to do it without jQuery?
Below is some code:

EDIT: added the suggested function for localstorage

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide_show_table(col_name)
{
 var checkbox_val=document.getElementById(col_name).value;
 if(checkbox_val=="hide")
 {
  var all_col=document.getElementsByClassName(col_name);
  for(var i=0;i<all_col.length;i++)
  {
   all_col[i].style.display="none";
  }
  document.getElementById(col_name+"_head").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById(col_name).value="show";
 }

 else
 {
  var all_col=document.getElementsByClassName(col_name);
  for(var i=0;i<all_col.length;i++)
  {
   all_col[i].style.display="table-cell";
  }
  document.getElementById(col_name+"_head").style.display="table-cell";
  document.getElementById(col_name).value="hide";
 }
}
</script>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
  const checkbox = document.getElementById('fdt_col');
  checkbox.checked = !!localStorage.getItem('checked');
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
localStorage.setItem('checked', this.checked);});
}
</script>


echo"<input type='checkbox' name='fdt_col' value='hide' id='fdt_col'
onchange='hide_show_table(this.id);' checked>some text</input><br/>";
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I see you're using Vanilla javascript so you can use the `localStorage` like so:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const checkbox = document.getElementById('fdt_col');
  checkbox.checked = !!localStorage.getItem('checked');
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {localStorage.setItem('checked', this.checked);});

}
```

### Note about `localStorage` vs `sessionStorage`

[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) will save your items on all tabs while [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is to be used if you need separation between tabs

Comment: I just tried it. I wrote the id of my checkbox instead of bar and called my key 'checked' instead of 'foo'. 
And now the console says: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: The console now says: TypeError: checkbox is null.
I now added if (typeof checked !== 'undefined')... The error disappeared  but it I still get the initial status after the refresh

Comment: `document.getElementById` must be passed a string as a parameter so you want to: `document.getElementById('fdt_col')`

Comment: `typeof checked !== 'undefined'` will always return `false` in this case. you can make this `if` after you've defined `checkbox` but only after you define it

Comment: I've updated my answer again to contain your class name

Comment: Can you please provide a working example? jsfiddle?